# Merge container disks

Tags: disk-utility, mojave

[image]

I want to merge the empty container disk3 to existing container disk2. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think disk is both partitioned and has **container** inside **partition** Container disk2, which is in use. And **second partition** Container disk 3, which was created probably by accident:

[image: Partition vs Add volume]

So press Partition button when hard disk is selected (ST1000LM..) and choose **Partition**. Then select unused partition and click [-] (minus) sign.

Then select the main partition and increase its size to max:

[image: Partition disk]

Click apply and you are done.

Comment: i dont have points to upvote Arunas's answer but i couldnt pass without saying thanks. Really thanks mate

Comment: Pleasure to help :) welcome!